# AWS EB environment deployed with CLI not showing in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I manage to run `eb deploy` successfully from the command prompt and get the following:

```
2023-05-21 21:27:31    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
```

And when I run `eb list` I get as result the name of my environment `* simply-dev`.

I can run `eb status --verbose` and see everything looks healthy/green.

```
Environment details for: simply-dev
  Application name: simply
  Region: us-east-2
  Deployed Version: app-230523_221320835290
  Environment ID: e-rdyf63m2dr
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.2
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: exit.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2023-05-23 21:17:44.717000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
  Running instances: 1
           i-034a7471b6b368e1b: healthy
```

However, when I run `eb console`, the console opened in the internet browser does not show any application or environment and keeps loading endlessly. I also checked I am in the same region and both show the same Account ID. I also tried deploying in other regions with the same result.

[image: AWS EB Error]

**Any idea of why I cannot see the environment in the AWS console?**

I am checking the logs from `eb logs --zip` but I don't really understand much. Any idea what to look for?
[image: Logs]

The Chrome Developers Tools shows an error but I am not sure if it is related to this:
[image]

Comment: Does the Logs tab tell you anything suspicious and just a random suggestion to try logging out and logging again?

Comment: Check the console in Chrome Developer Tools for errors. If there are any, they might shed light on what's going on. My first guess would be the role you're using in the console not having the right permissions.

Comment: @ArpitJain there are 13 log files from running `eb logs --zip`. Is there anyone in particular that could be helpful to check? See updated description of the question on the logs I see.

Comment: @kichik I checked the Chrome Developer Tools, it shows an error but not sure if this is related to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS support finally gave me the solution. Basically, it seems I was creating my environment in another account. It seems there are AWS credentials (found at `C:/Users/Your_User/.aws/config`) but EB cli has its own credentials which are input as part of the `eb init` command, and can be found at the same `.aws/config` file with the profile named "eb-cli". The access key credentials here are the ones that are used by default when setting up the environment.

As an example, once I setup the credentials using `aws configure`, my output is:

```
# cat .aws/config
[default]
 
# cat .aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = abc
aws_secret_access_key = 123
```

After running `eb init` command, I have the following credentials:

```
# cat .aws/config
[default]
 
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = xyz
aws_secret_access_key = 890
 
# cat .aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = abc
aws_secret_access_key = 123
```

So in my case, somehow my "eb-cli" profile contained valid credentials in another account (how I did that, I don't know). The fix is to navigate to the credentials file and change the access keys for the "eb-cli" profile ones found in the .aws/config.

Answer (score 1):

have you navigate to EC2 dashboard and make sure there has a running VM instance with ID `i-034a7471b6b368e1b`?. If it not exist, You better ask AWS technical support regarding to this case

Comment: I went to EC2 Dashboard/Instances [https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-2#Instances:] but it appears empty. However, if in the CLI I run `eb open` it opens the application :S